# How to combine the same function for different types of argument in scala

Tags: scala

E.g., I had two exactly the same `lessThan` function for `JsNumber` and `JsString`.

```
def ltNum(left: JsNumber, right: JsNumber, order: SortOrder.Value): Boolean = {
  if (left.value < right.value) {
    order == SortOrder.ASC
  } else {
    order == SortOrder.DSC
  }
}

def ltStr(left: JsString, right: JsString, order: SortOrder.Value): Boolean = {
  if (left.value < right.value) {
    order == SortOrder.ASC
  } else {
    order == SortOrder.DSC
  }
}
```

These two functions are exactly the same but the input argument types. `JsNumber` and `JsString` are from the library `play-json` that extend from the `JsValue`. However, the `value` and `<` is not part of the super's traits. Any good ideas to combine these to one general function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide some proof that both types support ordering. You can do this with the `Ordering` typeclass:

```
// you'll have to figure out a good place to put these
// they'll need to be in scope whenever you *call* the `lt` method
implicit val jsNumberOrdering: Ordering[JsNumber] = Ordering.by(_.value)
implicit val jsStringOrdering: Ordering[JsString] = Ordering.by(_.value)

def lt [A <: JsValue : Ordering] (left: A, right: A, order: SortOrder.Value): Boolean = {
  import Ordering.Implicits._ // will give you the `<` method
  if (left < right) {
    order == SortOrder.ASC
  } else {
    order == SortOrder.DSC
  }
}
```

Comment: op also needs to actually implement ordering for those two and put it in scope.

Comment: @Łukasz Hmm... for some reason i thought that existed already... good catch. Updated.

Comment: I am not sure if it exists, but even if it doesn,t it is worth mentioning, as the answer to the question is actually: "use type classes", and it will be easier to understand what's going on for OP ;p

Answer (score 0):

This is where generics come in. You should be able to define something like

```
def lt[T](left: T, right: T, order: SortOrder.Value): Boolean
```

In your case, you may also want to add a bound if needed -

```
def lt[T <: JsValue](left: T, right: T, order: SortOrder.Value): Boolean
```

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/upper-type-bounds.html

Comment: Also commonly referred to as 'Type parameterization' in Scala.

Comment: Don't see how that helps, `T` doesn't have a `<` method